# Passing parameter from Azure Event Hubs to stored procedure in Azure SQL DB in Azure Function

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I have EventHub trigger which triggers my Azure Function and I need to pass **partiton_key** from Event Hub to SQL input binding to execute stored procedure.
Here is my function.json file:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "eventHubTrigger",
      "name": "events",
      "direction": "in",
      "eventHubName": "playerinput",
      "connection": "AzureEventHubConnectionString",
      "cardinality": "many",
      "consumerGroup": "$Default"
    },
    { 
      "name": "referenceTable",
      "type": "sql",
      "direction": "in",
      "commandText": "GetPlayerStats",
      "commandType":"storedProcedure",
      "parameters": "@player_id = {PartitionKey}",
      "connectionStringSetting": "SqlConnectionString"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is code in python:

```
from typing import List
import logging
import json
import azure.functions as func


def main(events: List[func.EventHubEvent],referenceTable:func.SqlRowList):

    for event in events:
        logging.info(event)
        logging.info('Python EventHub trigger processed an event: %s',
                        event.get_body().decode('utf-8'))
        
        rows = [json.loads(row.to_json()) for row in referenceTable]
        logging.info(rows)
```

I tried to reference **partition_key** but when I start function I am getting error in logs. In microsoft docs the say: The Event Hubs trigger provides several metadata properties. Metadata properties can be used as part of binding expressions in other bindings or as parameters in your code. The properties come from the EventData class (link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-trigger?tabs=python-v1%2Cin-process%2Cnodejs-v4%2Cfunctionsv2%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-python#event-metadata).

Answer (score 0):

When you have `cardinality` set to `many`, you are processing an array of events instead of a single event which is why the binding expression errors out.

Removing the setting or changing the value to `one` should do the trick.